# Using a list to receive rows from a database

Tags: c#, wpf, database, xaml, database-connection

I am trying to populate a list whilst a database connection, I have gotten my MVVM down correctly, but I have no idea how to define a list, then in that list, connect to a db and populate the fields. Can anyone help? My database works fine...

`UserRepository`

```
public class UserRepository: IUserRepository
{

    private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connectionToDB;

    private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;

    // Get the data set generated by the sqlStatement
    public System.Data.DataSet getDataSet(string sqlStatement)
    {
        System.Data.DataSet dataSet;

        // creates the object dataAdapter to manipulate a table from the database
        dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, connectionToDB);

        // create the dataset
        dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        //return the dataSet
        return dataSet;
    }
    public List<Users> GetUsers()
    {
        List<Users> users;


        // Database connection to go here along with the list population
        // Something like this?
        //
        // new User
        //     ID = 
        //     FirstName = 
        //     LastName =   

        //  Users = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_users);



        return users;
    }


}
```

`DBViewModel`

```
public class DBDisplayViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Users> users;

    public DBDisplayViewModel()
    {
        Load();
    }

    public IUserRepository UserRepository
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Users> Users
    {
        get
        {
            if (users == null)
            {
                users = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
            }

            return users;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                users = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        List<Users> users= UserRepository.GetUsers();
        Users= new ObservableCollection<Users>(users);
    }
}
```

`Users`

This just defines the `ID` `FirstName` `LastName` Properties

So to break it down: The information commented out in `UserRepository` needs to be created to pull in the database connection and the database values. Can anyone help? Much love!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the below code, will give idea

```
        public List<Users> GetUsers()
            {
                List<Users> users=new  List<Users> ();
                DataSet ds=getDataSet("Select FirstName,...... from Users")
                Users user;

                 foreach(DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                 {
                   user=new Users();
                   user.FirstName=row["firstname"].ToString();
                    ....
                    ....
                   users.Add(user)
                 }
                return users;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Question, it's telling me that I can't convert object to string on `user.FirstName=row["firstname"]`. how can I fix that?

Comment: Updated the code please check It should be user.FirstName=row["firstname"].ToString();

Comment: what about `list.Add(user)`? It's saying `list` does not exist in the context

Comment: Oh Its a typos, its should be users

Comment: So I've finally run all of my code, and I'm now getting an null error on this line ` List<Users> users= UserRepository.GetUsers();`

Comment: I've still got issues though. When I'm pulling the first List, the users value is always null...? Is it my code above that's the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96344/discussion-between-gajendra-and-badja).

Comment: I took your chat advice of `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count()` but it's saying there's no definition for count and the type arguments for the method cannot be inferred from the usage?